# Is there the term "majour fource" in English?

Tags: orthography, legalese

A person from the legal department replaced "major force" with "majour fource" in a document. I wanna know if this spelling has any background in the English language or is a typo.

Comment: Perhaps they mixed it up with _force majeure_: a legal term used in contracts to absolve both parties of responsibility in extreme conditions.

Comment: I asked if it is a typo and said "no". I fear asking her more cause I don't want to start an argument.

Comment: It looks like they did a global replace of *or* with *our* to correct words like *color* to *colour*.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing I might do to mock my British colleagues in EL&U chat.

Comment: I Googled it and two of the top four hits were your question, cross posted.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Did you mean to say "a global *replacement*"

Comment: Clearly, it was an editorial error. There's no question of the English language involved. Voting to close.

Comment: Whatever the original intended meaning, it's just plain wrong as "majour fource".  Kick it back for correction.

Comment: @WS2 - He meant to say "replace all".

Comment: Note that [*main force*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/by-main-force) actually does mean something specific and different.

Comment: I wanna know if you're actually concerned about grammar and spelling at all?

Comment: @Octopus, the case is real, if you have any doubts. As you can see, I am relatively new to this site, that's why I may look suspicious to you, but my intentions are legit. I am not a native English speaker, but as a writer in this language, I am concerned to publish a text in a correct form, not with typos, grammar or spelling errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Force majeure*

— meaning "superior force", is also known as cas fortuit (French) or casus fortuitus (Latin) "chance occurrence, unavoidable accident". It is a common clause in contracts that essentially frees both parties from liability or obligation when an extraordinary event or circumstance beyond the control of the parties, such as a war, strike, riot, crime, or an event described by the legal term act of God (such as hurricane, flooding, earthquake, volcanic eruption, etc.), prevents one or both parties from fulfilling their obligations under the contract. In practice, most force majeure clauses do not excuse a party's non-performance entirely, but only suspends it for the duration of the force majeure (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_majeure))

Comment: I was interested in the spelling, not the meaning.

Comment: Majour fource looks to me to be a half-remembered version of  Force majeure.